# Can't see the source code in DDD. how it cab be resolved?

Tags: c, ddd-debugger

I'm working with UBUNTU 16.04
Complied with gcc -g
I've tried to look for answers for that and couldn't find.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then please come back and [edit] your question, showing us what you tried, at best with a [example], and what happens against your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

when executing `DDD` (aka `gdb` with extensions) the source code must be visible from the directory where the `DDD` is executed.  The easiest way to have both the source and the executable in the same directory.

However, there are some commands that can be given to `DDD` to tell it where the source code is located.

Also, when the debugger is `GDB` or `DDD`, then for maximum flexibility instead of `-g` use `-ggdb3`

The source directory can be set with the command line parameter:

```
--directory=DIR    Search for source files in DIR.
```